# Apply css on above div element

Tags: html, css

i have two div . from second div a:hover  i want to add opacity on img

```
<div class="hide">
     <img src="/img.png">
</div>
<div class="onhover">
     <a class=""onhover_change>
</div>
```

If anyone have idea let me know.
I am not getting how to apply css on above div

Comment: It's not possible, CSS don't know parent/previous sibling selector. You're able to target just siblings and/or children elements.

Comment: As mentioned above, this is not possible with that HTML and just CSS. However you could use JS, or change the structure of your HTML (while keeping the output looking the same) If you are open to those solutions it would be worth mentioning it in your question what you can/cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your HTML Like

```css
.wrapper{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
    }
    .onhover{order:1}
    .hide{order:0}
    .onhover:hover + .hide{
      opacity:0.3;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="onhover">
        <a class=""onhover_change>dsd</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hide">
           <img src="/img.png">
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/w40jxaf5/3/